# How to stop the sprite kit update in swift?

Tags: swift

```
override func update(currentTime: NSTimeInterval) {
    // ... 
}
```

When my game is over, I want to stop the update in sprite kit.

Which function should I use in swift?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `bool` for that like when your game over just make that `true` and put if condition in your update method like:

```
override func update(currentTime: NSTimeInterval) {
    // It will execute till gameOver is false but when you make your gameOver true then it will not execute.
    if !gameOver {

        //Do your stuff
    }
}
```

Hope this will help you.